# How to restart a Nodemon server via code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

I have an array of JSON objects which gets updated at server start, however if I change info in the JSON via NodeJS FS (not by doing it myself) Nodemon doesn't restart, so I was wondering if it is possible to restart nodemon via code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but yes, you can send the nodemon process a SIGHUP signal, e.g.:

```
pkill -f -SIGHUP nodemon
```

And you could call this from node.js using child_process.exec. Here is a working example:

```js
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('poking nodemon to restart');
  exec('pkill -f -SIGHUP nodemon');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Would that kill it, or kill it and restart it

Comment: Neither, the nodemon will remain running but it will restart the app it is monitoring, which is what you want, right? Note that this is sending a Hang-up signal, not Terminate or Kill or Interrupt.

Comment: Did that help you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the watch list as by default it will monitor only js and coffee files.
You do that by --ext switch or -e

> nodemon -e  js,json

If you have typescript files too to worry about add them above

Comment: It automatically watches JSON